# Right Click > Edit not Showing up on HTML Documents

Tags: html, windows

When I go to an HTML Document in my file explorer, I right-click, but the `edit` option doesn't show up! I want to open the file in an editor. This is the code inside my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>An html test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Windows 10 64-bit latest version as of 5/16/20. Here are some screenshots:

[The Test HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4mRW.png)

[The Right-Click Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIBEE.png)

Comment: Haven't my solution solve your problem completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to desktop and press `windows + R`.

1. write `regedit` Press `Enter`.
2. go to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` expand it.
3. Then expand `*`.
4. Then expand `shell`.
5. `Right click` on `shell` and add `new key` and name it `Edit`.
6. Then `Right click` on `Edit` and add `new key` and name it `command`.
7. Then go to `Default` and `Right click` on it and `modify` it.
8. Paste that path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe""%1` in text box.

Then you will get edit option everywhere whenever you press right click.

Comment: This doesn't work. It opens my text editor (I used a different one) but not the file :(

Comment: It will definitely work fine. you may miss something

Comment: Ok, found a fix, added "%1" to the end of the .exe file

Comment: Also if you want it to show up only for html file then add this registry path ```HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.html\shell\Edit\command```

Answer (score 0):

Visit this [page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/edit-option-for-html-files-disappeared-from-right/42487363-e4ba-451b-85ef-d3ace93fd187?page=1&tab=MoreHelp), I think its the issue with your notepad.

Comment: Please provide a complete solution not just link. Thank you.

Comment: But I am using windows 10!

Answer (score 0):

(right click->edit) on windows will open the file with notepad

notepad is not defined to open .html file by default

You have two options :

1)you need to have another editor that sets itself as default while installing such as notepad++

2) you need to do right click-> open with->choose another app->select notepad and check (always use this app to open .html files) after that you will have edit option on right click for html files

Answer (score 0):

To edit the html file,

-- Right-click the file

-- Click on 'Open with'

-- Select your text editor (if no text editor is displayed, click on 'Choose Default Program'. Click on a text editor and then click OK). If you have not installed any text editor, click on 'Notepad'.

Comment: I would like to have it open with Chrome by default, but thank you for your effort!.

Answer (score 0):

Save this in a batch file `Add Edit Command To HTML.bat` & run:

```
reg add "HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.html\shell\Edit\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "notepad.exe \"%%1\"" /f
pause
```

This adds an Edit command to the `.html` file context menu to be open with Notepad.

If you don't have Notepad in `PATH`, then put full path to Notepad instead of `notepad.exe`

The `SystemFileAssociations` is the location where you specify for example the `.html` file type association for context menu and in the `shell` you put the `Edit command`.